# Rails save multiple records from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following hash holding a user's `name` and `items_sold`:

```
{"dave"=>9, "steve"=>20}
```

I created it in my `Rawdatum Index` action through:

```
@consolidated_rawdata = Rawdatum.all.group(:user).sum(:items_sold)
```

What I want to do now is to save both objects from that hash (dave & steve) with a single action (a single click on a button) to a table called `reports` with two columns: `user` and `items_sold` like so:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if that counts as a single action, but you can iterate through the hash like this:

```
@consolidated_rawdata.each {|name, items_sold| Report.create(user: 
  name, items_sold: items_sold)}
```

Comment: Where do I have to put that? In my Report create action? I am now in the Rawdata index action/view.

Comment: I guess that depends based on your application. You can make a button that calls an action on the ReportsController that querys the consolidated_data and then creates the reports.

Answer (score 0):

if a action is just a single click then its really simple. We can just loop threw the hash and save the record

I would put this in a model like Reports

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  #Report.create_consolidated_rawdata
  def self.create_consolidated_rawdata
    @consolidated_rawdata = Rawdatum.all.group(:user).sum(:items_sold)
    @consolidated_rawdata.do |name, items_sold| 
      Report.create(user: name, items_sold: items_sold)
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that this works

Comment: Where do I have to put that? In my Report create action? I am now in the Rawdata index action/view.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. i will try this one later to make my code nicer. :-)

Comment: I am glad that I could help